# Is it possible to change a page's body background with a jquery slick carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

If I have multiple divs in a carousel and want one of the divs to change the page's background, would that be possible?

while the carousel is ON the div, not hovering or clicked on

```
if ($('.carousel').slick('slickGoTo', 1)){ //if slick is on slide index 1
//change to another page where I've already changed the page's background
                location.href = page location;
//or change the body's background
let body=document.getElementsByTagName("body");
     body.style.background = "image url";
});
```

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/milytulip/L27nhvbr/

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection not a single element. Body is simple to query as a property of document... `document.body`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), this should work:

```
$('. carousel').on('afterChange', function(slick, currentSlide){
  if (currentSlide===1) {
     $('body').addClass('specialBG');
  } else {
     $('body').removeClass('specialBG');
  }
});
```

and then have the style ready for the special  slide

```
body.specialBG {
   background-color:#333;
}
```

Comment: hm, not working, but this is what I'm looking for. As of right now none of the specialBG are being read